# Unit тесты для javascript с моками

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, mockito

Как можно тестировать javascript с моками 
хотелось бы запускать тест чтобы при этом запускался эмулятор реста и проверка, догадываюсь что это не одна либа будет, какой микс либов посоветуют

Comment: выхотите mock или эмулировать?

Comment: mock и эмулятор - это очень разные вещи. mock проверяет, что был вызов внешней (по отношению к текущему объекту) функции. эмулятор же притворяется чем-то полноценным. вот хорошая статья [Mocks Aren't Stubs](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)

Comment: есть куча библиотек для подобного, но скорей всего вам не нужен эмулятор. для тестирования достаточно mock и stub.

Comment: если это будт юнит тесты, то не советую использовать эмулятор совсем.

Comment: посмотрите на [mountebank](http://www.mbtest.org/)

Comment: @mikhail-vaysman Спасибо, это то что надо

Comment: а какую библиотеку используете для тестирования?

Comment: @mikhail-vaysman сейчас простые тесты написаны с использованием karma

Comment: karma это просто запускалка тестов. но скорей всего у вас jasmine. там все есть. и в документации подробно описано. можете так же посмотреть на jest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как можно использовать **mock** для тестов на **jasmine**

```
describe("какой-то тест", function () {
    it("mock объекта", function () {
        var functionUnderTest = function (externalObject) {
            externalObject.callMe();
        };

        var mock = jasmine.createSpyObj("mock", ["callMe"]);
        functionUnderTest(mock);
        expect(mock.callMe).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: а для чего можно использовать mountebank, кроме как заглушка для сервера когда сервер еще не готов или как то можно объединить с Jasmine

Comment: для интеграционных тестов

Comment: А можно пару слов про интеграционные тесты, что используется с mountebank для написания тестов

Comment: на СО были ответы про это. используют - selenium, phantomjs, zombiejs и т,д,

Comment: да я видел их и больше склоняюсь к seleniuiim, но что рекомендуете вы

Comment: я же не знаю ваших требований! к тому же я считаю, что интеграционных тестов нужно всего 3-5% от общего числа тестов.

Comment: понятно, спасибо